# Drawer Navigation inside a specific Tab that has Stack Navigation in React Native with Expo Router, Possible?

Tags: react-native, expo, navigation-drawer

Hello I am using React Native with expo router, I implemented Bottom Tab navigation, I have a Tab for a file named 'settings.js' and another Tab for a folder named 'explore' inside that folder I implemented Stack Navigation with an Additional screen (file called results.js)
What I am trying to achieve is for that explore tab I want to have a drawer navigation as well, I managed to make a drawer navigation but for that folder it doesn't work, I'm afraid it might have something to do with the Stack navigation possibly? not sure.

code for the _layout.js file inside the Explore folder:

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default () => {
    return (
        // The first screen it will show will be the first one under the Stack.
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen name='index' options={{title:'Welcome (index) Page', headerTitleAlign: 'center',}} />
            <Stack.Screen name='searchResult' options={{title:'Search Result' ,headerTitleAlign: 'center' }} />
        </Stack>
    );
};
```

code for the _layout.js file inside the Drawer Folder (that is inside the explore):

```
import { Drawer } from "./Drawer";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return <Drawer />;
}
```

inside the drawer folder I have the Drawer.tsx file following the expo router docs:

```
import {
    // Import the creation function
    createDrawerNavigator,
    // Import the types
    DrawerNavigationOptions,
  } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
  
  import { withLayoutContext } from "expo-router";
  
  const { Navigator } = createDrawerNavigator();
  
  // This can be used like `<Drawer />`
  export const Drawer = withLayoutContext<
    DrawerNavigationOptions,
    typeof Navigator
  >(Navigator);
```

Thank you for your time.

As mentioned above..